# Angular no me quiere instalar porque el npm de node esta fallando en mi windows

Tags: java, nodejs, angular, typescript, npm

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola estoy intentando de resolver este error ya llevo tres dias mirando el porque no instala los archivos de angular, se que node esta funcionando bien ¿pero alguien sabe el porque  el npm no quiere funcionar correctamente? he desinstalado y he vuelto instalar el npm, pero sigue con el mismo problema tengo una maquina virtual en mi pc corriendo Debian dentro de mi computadora con node y me funciona bien los proyectos, pero en windows me falla el npm y no puedo instalar Angular. La razon por la que quiero trabajar en windows es porque ayi tengo el id de java y quiero usarlo como backend para realizar un crud. Tambien yo he instalado las variables de entono en el path para resolver el problema que no me reconoce el comando interno y externo Alguien tiene alguna otra idea?
. C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin
. C:\Program Files\nodejs\ he pegado estos dos
pero sigue apareciendo la misma imagen e intente de ignorar el mensaje y trabajar asi ya que el pues aparentaba que trabajaba bien entonces decidí crear un proyecto de Angular y me salio un error, al parecer de java, agregue las variables de entorno de java y se que eso ya no se hace actualmente ¡pero lo ensaye! y sin ningun resultado tambien me acuerdo que anteriromente instale un programa que se llama balena etcher este programa flashea sdcards para que tenga un nuevo sistema operativo y tambien me presentaba fallas me decia ERR ENON JAVA entonces estoy viendo que la posibilidad puede ser algo de java no se ustedes que opinan?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
.

Comment: Has incluido npm en las variables del sistema?

Comment: Si creo que el problema ocurre por java y me esta molestando los programas que trabajan con script. Por el momento estoy trabajando en  virtual box con distro debian y ayi tengo instalado node y npm y me funcionan bien pero no tengo instalado java en la maquina virtual. todavia no he solucionado esto en la version de windows